# How to format Price / Currency text according to user locale in XML view?

Tags: sapui5, locale

```xml
<Text text="{Someobject>/Price}"/>
```

Is it possible to format text straight on the XML view, instead of setting it on `Someobject>/Price` property?

I want to **format that price field based on user locale**, but don't really want to change the model, just the text in the UI.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatter is just "presentational": it does not affect the model, it changes only the way the data is displayed on the view...

Go for the formatter ;-)

EDIT:
For the sake of completeness, a [link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8.html) to the SDK explanation of how the formatters work